# python dictionary assignment issue---assign all the values whichi is not expected

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code, and firstly I generated a dictionary which has three layers. Then I assign an element to a3[0][0]['boy'] but I get all the keys assigned. If anyone knows why this is so, please help me with this. Thank you really much.

```
a1={}
a2={}
a3= {}
for p_type in ['boy','girl']:
    a1[p_type] = 0
for m in range(2):
     a2[m] = a1
for p in range(2):
    a3[p] = a2
print(a3)
a3[0][0]['boy']=100
a3
```

following is the result

```
{0: {0: {'boy': 0, 'girl': 0}, 1: {'boy': 0, 'girl': 0}}, 1: {0: {'boy': 0, 'girl': 0}, 1: {'boy': 0, 'girl': 0}}}

Out[12]:
{0: {0: {'boy': 100, 'girl': 0}, 1: {'boy': 100, 'girl': 0}},
 1: {0: {'boy': 100, 'girl': 0}, 1: {'boy': 100, 'girl': 0}}}
```

Comment: Variables and dictionary elements hold references to objects. You use multiple references but they point to the same dictionary object. Read about `dict.copy()` for a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to make something on the order of a 3-dimensional array, then you should use tuples for the keys.  I'm guessing you want something like `a3[0,0,'boy'] = 100`.   Note that you don't need parentheses inside the brackets.  It's the comma that makes a tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: @Michael Butscher,yeah,thanks.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Can you post your comment as an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @alex Done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and dictionary elements hold references to objects. You use multiple references but they point to the same dictionary object.

`dict.copy()` creates a real copy.